# Google Chrome MSI Versions

Tags: google-chrome

Google Chrome offers an MSI installer useful for enterprise deployments. However, I have noticed that when I install Chrome using this MSI there is a version number mismatch.

If I open Chrome and click on "About Google Chrome" from the menu, it says version 35.0.1916.153.

However, if I open Control Panel and pull up my program list, it says Google Chrome version 65.223.153.

I haven't been able to find any documentation from Google that can explain this version discrepancy, and it makes it very difficult to run reporting to tell me if the software is properly patching itself, given that all reporting systems use the same Registry data that shows up in Control Panel. Google doesn't appear to track their enterprise version numbers anywhere on their site.

Can someone help explain how to translate between these version numbers, or where Google might keep such data?

Answer (score 0):

The following bugs thread at the Chromium website documents the issue you are seeing, unfortunately with no resolution:

> The problem is that the DisplayVersion (MSI version) has limits on its
>   format.  It has to be in format X.X.X, whereas Chrome versions are
>   X.X.X.X  There is an algorithm to convert Chrome versions to MSI
>   versions, but it's pretty complex.
>
> See bug 58031 for a similar issue -- it would be nice to show the MSI
>   version in the about dialog.

[MSI DisplayVersion to match Chrome version](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=67348)

Comment: Please refrain from submitting link-only answers in the future.